# Git fetch new branch from URI without adding it as a remote

Tags: git, fetch, pull, git-remote

I have several branches of a repository on a VM, each checked out and built in a separately cloned repo, so I can work on any branch and build it incrementally.

I want to pull from 'vm:repo-branch-a' to my laptop, which means creating a local branch on the laptop and running 'git fetch vm:repo-branch-a'. But it's cumbersome because when creating the branch on the laptop, I have to know at which commit to create it.

Is there a way to pull the branch without adding vm:repo-branch-... as a remote ? Since I have 2 or 10 clones on the vm, and I delete them when I'm done working on a branch, I'd rather not have to create a remote on the laptop, but preferably just pass the ssh URI to 'git fetch' or 'git pull'.

Comment: Are you familiar with [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) ? That might be an easier solution to having each branch checked out in its own directory.

Comment: If all the clones on the VM are clones of the same repository, you can checkout the branch you expect on your laptop from that central repository. How do you choose what branches are checked out on your VM ?